# Mesh deforms on one side of model when attaching rig

Tags: mesh, rigging, edit-mode

I'm working on a humanoid character with a rig setup like shown here

[image]

When I attach the mesh model to the armature rig (I choose the mesh first, then the armature, and choose armature deform with automatic weight), the left side of the mesh by the characters hip gets pushed in towards her center. Like here

[image]

I think maybe the problem has something to do with using the X-mirror Mesh Option because it actually worked at one time, it was when I made all the bones symmetrical it seemed to break my model ...

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to apply all scales to your mesh before you add a rig. Make also sure the origins of rig and mesh match.
Out of my head it's ctrl a to apply scales